# ¿como puedo recuperar wordpress que elimine por error?

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

Usando el instalador de aplicaciones de un cpanel borre sin querer la instalacion del wordpress, hay alguna forma de recuperar los archivos y la web ? ya me comunique con el hosting y me mandaron a pagar para que me ayuden los tecnicos

Comment: Si has borrado los únicos archivos de esa página web que tenías, despídete de ella. Una vez lo borras en el servidor ya está borrado.
Para ello existen las copias de seguridad.

Comment: La base de datos posiblemente siga ahi, talvez, tambien puedes revisar los backups, si tienes suerte puede que haya algun backup hecho por el hosting, otra opcion es revisar el basurero del hosting, talvez esten ahi los archivos viejos, si despues de todo esto no logras encontrar los archivos, pues no creo que haya mas que se pueda hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Algunos hosting con cpanel tienen una papelera, puedes verificar ahí. pero lo mas recomendable es que contactes el hosting ya que ellos suelen hacer backups de sus servidores.